# Taking the logarithm of a periodic function

Tags: logarithms, multivalued-functions

I've been wondering how we take the logarithm of a periodic function. At least I think that's what I've been wondering - but I may have confused the terminology. Anyway, take, for example, the expression:

$\ln (-1)$

Well, $e^{i\pi} = -1$, so, by the definition of logarithms, $\ln (-1) = i\pi$. But $e^{3i\pi} = -1$ and so does $e^{5i\pi}$, etc., etc. So $\ln (-1)$ could also equal $3i\pi$.

So, is the logarithm function multivalued - are $i\pi$, $3i\pi$ and $5i\pi$ all valid answers - or do we take a kind of "principle value", or something else?

It's been a long time since I did logs and quite a long time since I did $e$, so my understanding of the basic principles may just be off.

Comment: I'd say you're basically right, though sometimes $\ln(z)$ for complex $z$ is defined by choosing a "branch" to make it single valued. The branch is defined by restricting the $\theta$ in the polar form of the log, to a half-open interval of length $2\pi$

Comment: If I may add to this: the branch @coffeemath specifies is just one of the (infinitely many) possible branches that make the log single-valued. There is a whole subject in mathematics that is basically about multi-valued functions and involves Riemann surfaces.